# Font mapping issues after manual newtx install, CentOS7

Tags: fonts, pdftex, newtx

Apologies if there is already an answer. I have been searching the forums and found some related questions/answers, but still could not solve my issue. I have `TeX Live 2013` installed on my `CentOS7` machine and up to now had no problems. However, the new style files for the journals to which I frequently submit articles now include `newtx`. I discovered (through these forums) that one cannot automatically get this through `TeX Live` on `CentOS7`, but managed to obtain it from CTAN. I followed the installation instructions, and the material is now in my `TEXMFLOCAL` (`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local`); in addition I checked that the `"Map newtx.map"` line appears in all the `texmf*/web2c/updmap.cfg` files.

On running `pdflatex` after this installation, there was a problem with a missing style file `fontaxes.sty`, which I also then installed from CTAN as per the instructions.
On running `pdflatex` again after these installations, I get the following output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./orogen-review1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(./agujournal.cls
Document Class: agujournal 08/06/2016
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/tex/newtxtext.sty
`newtxtext' v1.5, 2016/08/12 Text macros taking advantage of TeX-Gyre Termes fo
nts (msharpe) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf/tex/latex/fontaxes.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)) 
No Babel
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/tex/newtxmath.sty
`newtxmath' v1.5, 2016/08/12 Math macros based on txfonts (msharpe)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)) (./lineno.sty)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/ragged2e.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotating/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty) (./natbib.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/tex/t1ntxtlf.fd)

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ntx-Regular-tlf-t1

/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ntx-Regular-tlf-t1.

/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?

mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntx-Regular-tlf-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ntx-Regular-tlf-t1
! I can't find file `ntx-Regular-tlf-t1'.
<*> ...g:=1; nonstopmode; input ntx-Regular-tlf-t1

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...g:=1; nonstopmode; input ntx-Regular-tlf-t1

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ntx-Regular-tlf-t1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ntx-Regular-tlf-t1' failed to make ntx-Regular-tlf-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/ntxtlf/m/n/10=ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM)
 file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10 \begin{document}

?
```

It looks like the system is failing to find the new fonts, which are present in my `TEXMFLOCAL` directory (subdirectory `tfm`).
I've seen similar types of questions elsewhere in the forum, but have not yet found a solution from the resulting threads that works on my system. Can anyone advise?